# Unary operator within main and static method

Tags: java

I have following two codes, and in the process of knowing how unary operation works within SOP, and main method. Could someone let me know how values of "i" is calculated within main, and also when it gets within the static method.

Any detail background operation of things will be appreciated, as I need to build a logic which will help me understand other related codes as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class R
{

    static int test( int i)
    {

        return i--;

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int i=0;
        System.out.println(test(i++));
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0;
        System.out.println(test(i--));
        System.out.println(test(i));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0
1
0
-1
```

Second One :

```
class S
{

    static int test( int i)
    {

        return ++i;

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int i=0;
        System.out.println(test(i++));
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0;
        System.out.println(test(i--));
        System.out.println(test(i));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1
1
1
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding your programs behavior is to remember that for **primitive** types Java uses **call by value** instead of **call by reference**.

Thus the name `i` in your `test` function will not reference the same value that is referenced by the name `i` in your `main` function.

### By Example

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {

  int i=0;
  System.out.println(test(i++));
```

What's happening here is:

- i's value is increased by `i++` to 1
- next the `test` method is called with the old value of i, thus `test (0)`
- the return vale of `test (0)` will be printed to stdout.

To determine the return value of `test (0)` take a closer look at the `test` method:

```
  static int test( int i) {
    return i--;
  }
```

What happens here is:

- the value passed in referenced by the name `i` is decreased by `i--`
- the old value of i is returned

As a value of `0` was passed in the resulting return value is `0`, which is the value that gets printed by:

```
System.out.println(test(i++));
```

in your main method. The next line:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Will print the value named `i` in main to stdout. As a **copy** of the value of `i` got passed to the `test` method the old value is still unchanged. Thus the number `1` will be printed to stdout.

### Now it's up to you

Having shown by example how to trace the program flow for the first two results of your code using the same pattern you should be able to explain the other results yourself.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation, that really helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function "test" in class "R" is pointless:
It always returns the value which was used to call the function.
(Because of the post decrement and the call by value)